# extensible and modular ORM for asp.net mvc

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, ef-code-first

I am developing an asp.net mvc project which consist of a core library and other libraries (as modules). In core biliary I defined main entities like UserAccount, Logging and etc and warp them in a class which is inherited from  DbContext. Every single module has its own entity and model, and every module can be added to main project later, I mean they are not already built. Consider a scenario where I have create a new module, which contains News, Comments and Category entities, I want to plug this to main application, and also use the DbContext defined in core library, but as you know, in Code-First Approach, it will throw an exception, and want me to re-create the database, because the model has changed.

Is there any solution for this problem ? and way to make DbContext extensible ? Somebody suggested GenericRepository but I don`t know how to make it work with my problem (I already use GenericRepository  for core entities). Some guy has declared in his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142209/modular-applications-with-entity-framework-code-only-and-asp-net-mvc) that it is possible with nHibernate. Is it really works for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is recreating the database you can use SQL migrations for incremental database development. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx

Comment: In the article, hanselman mentioned "console inside Visual Studio", where is this console located?

Comment: I uses the console package manager and it output this error 'The term 'update-database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,', I even updated to last version of EF.

Comment: you need to install `Nugt pakag manager console` first. Use `Tools->Extension manager` to install it. And then using `Nueget Packag Manager` you need to install 'SQLMigrations'.

Comment: I already have 'Nugt pakag manager console' installed in visual studio and I successfully installed SQLMigrations, with out any errors.

Comment: Have you installed `Entity Framework - 4.1 Update 1` http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26825

Comment: Yes I also downloaded and installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on msdn community : [Extending DbContext for modular programming](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2d090f46-0d65-4f0c-bd23-ea60ee6dc45c)